# How to allow a node to be created, updated and deleted by the creator but not by other users in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My app's content is generated by the user. I want each user to access and edit his own data (the nodes he creates). So the user creates a "clips" node and a "clipOwners" node if the nodes are empty and he should also be able also to update any of these nodes and child nodes if he is the owner. Another user shouldn't be able to create a new node if the node pushKey (i.e. "$11111111") is already taken.
Here is my database structure:

```
                 clips {
 variable Key >>>   "111111111111" : {
                      "MACaddress" : "111111111111",
                      "comments" : "",
                      "created" : "Mon Apr 16 2018 12:40:13 GMT+0100 (BST)",
                      "inRoom" : "-LADDm48Uqabm1bcQGOw",
                      "ins" : {
                         "1523878813443" : true
                      },
                      "name" : "1",
                      "outs" : {
                         "1523878813443" : true
                      },
                      "ownerID" : "QpMHsVHHRrMvk92rbSQvcYEv4en1"
                   },
                   "222222222222" : {
                      "MACaddress" : "222222222222",
                      "comments" : "",
                      "created" : "Mon Apr 16 2018 12:40:13 GMT+0100 (BST)",
                      "inRoom" : "-LADDm48Uqabm1bcQGOw",
                      "ins" : {
                         "1523878813443" : true
                      },
                      "name" : "1",
                      "outs" : {
                         "1523878813443" : true
                      },
                      "ownerID" : "QpMHsVHHRrMvk92rbSQvcYEv4en1"
                   }
                },


                 "clipOwners" : {
                     "111111111111": "QpMHsVHHRrMvk92rbSQvcYEv4en1"           
                     "222222222222": "QpMHsVHHRrMvk92rbSQvcYEv4en1", 
                 }
```

I am trying this but the "ownerID" child node keeps on being updated by another user if another user tries to write to the same $MACaddress:

```
    "clips": {  
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || newData.exists()",
        "$MACaddress":{
          "ownerID": {
              ".validate": "!data.exists() || newData.val() === root.child('clipOwner').child($MACaddress).val()",

            }
        }
    },
    "clipOwners": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "newData.exists()",
      "$MACaddress": {

      },
```

Why is it behaving like that?
Any ideas on how I can lock this thing?

Comment: Is changing your datastructure an option?

Comment: yes @AndréKool. provided the $MACaddress is the key for the clips and that the rules work

Comment: Is this only about users not being able to write other users data or also about not being able to have duplicate keys? (in the last case how are the keys generated exactly?)

Comment: it's about both. the user types the Keys in an input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current write rules you only check if data (not) exists. In this answer i will only focus on the write rules to make sure you can't have duplicate keys (see clipOwners rules) and you can only write to your own data (see clips rules):

```
"clipOwners": {
  ".read": true,
  "$MACaddress": {
      //Only create or delete are possible and value is the user uid
      ".write": "(!data.exists() || !newData.exists()) && (newData.val() == auth.uid || data.val() == auth.uid)"
  }
},
"clips": {  
    ".read": "true",
    "$MACaddress":{
      //The $MACaddress has to exist in the clipOwners node and its value has to be the user uid
      ".write": "root.child('clipOwners/'+$MACaddress).exists() && root.child('clipOwners/'+$MACaddress).val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

When writing you first have to write the $MACaddress in the clipOwners node because this will be used to check if the user can write to the clips node.

You can take a look at [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example) for a simular case.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho Could you maybe update your question with actual data from your database and the write code you are using that should fail/succeed?

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using to write to your question? It is hard for me to understand how my answer is failing based on your comments. And maybe clean up some redundant comments to keep this organised.

Comment: @JoaoAlvesMarrucho For deleting data you have to make sure you first delete the data in clips and than delete the data in clipowner because the data in clipowner is used to determine if a user can write (or delete) to the clips node

Comment: that did it! Thank you for your help! :D